# In AWS cloudwatch detect lambda errors without certain text

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We have a lambda handling events from a queue. When it runs into an error that could be retried, our lambda code throws an exception, and that causes the event to be retried later on by sqs.

However, these exceptions events count as Errors for the default Cloudwatch 'Error' metric for lambdas.

I'd like to have an alarm for Errors that do not contain a text that indicates it's retryable (e.g. "Retryable failure"). I can make alarms on the text of the log, however I don't see how the standard 'Error' metric decides something is an error, and so I see no way to make an alarm that detects "log entries that are an error but do not contain 'Retryable failure'".

I could make an alarm that detects what happens on an exception, but I guess this wouldn't catch whatever comes out if the error comes from the AWS Lambda system (e.g. when it would not be able to start our function).

Comment: Not possible with built-in cloudwatch metrics. You can monitor the logs, filter for something, create a metric from that and put alert on top of that. But then you cannot detect actual lambda errors that do not show up in your log. You would need to change your lambda to catch ***ALL*** errors and do custom logging in case of any error and then filter the logs based on the different types of errors. And then you would need to rethrow the error such that lambda actually retries the failed invocation. And you always run the risk of something breaking before your code is reached and missing it.